# What is the equivalent for SolrDocument in solrnet

Tags: solr, indexing, solrnet

In the solrj api there is a way to post a file simply by building a SolrDocument with fields described by keys and values.
Is there an eqivalent way in solrnet? 
I simply want to index an xml file without mapping it with a POCO object first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the **Fully loose mapping** section of the [SolrNet Mapping](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Mapping.md) documentation for an example of how to index data without first mapping it to a POCO object. As compared to SolrJ you will build a `Dictionary<string,object>` with your keys and values that match the fields in your schema.

Comment: Ok . Got it. But it will cause troble when the xml contains two docs, won't it?

Comment: If the XML contains multiple docs, you will need to split each document into its own Dictionary object to send to Solr.

Comment: First , thank you.   If i get you right , anyway,  I'll have to modify/read the xml as .net object and go throgh the nodes. Any chance to use XSLT for that?

Comment: Based on what you are describing, you might be better served to use XSLT to transform your XML into the appropriate Solr XML Message format - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages and just make the Update call via direct Http calls and not worry about using the SolrNet client. You might also want to explore the Solr DataImportHandler - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler as it can assist with document transformation during indexing.

Comment: @itzikgili you don't need to manipulate Solr's XML messages when you use SolrNet, if that's what you mean.